# MongoDB node.js Update Function not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a whole document, but the update function does not complete and at the end of the request the server responds with a 504 http timeout. here's the function:

```
var updateCallback = function (err, up_teacher) {
    if(err)
        throw err;
    res.send(200, {message : "Teacher updated!"});
}
Teacher.update({_id: teacher._id}, teacher.toObject(), {w: 1, multi: true}, updateCallback);
```

I'm not sure if this is how you update a whole document (i.e. passing `teacher.toObject()` parameter), although I've seen in another question around here that this was the way, is it correct?

Comment: If `teacher` is a Mongoose doc it would be better to just call [`save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) on it.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use multi, I think the save function does not have that option...

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't really make sense as you're finding the doc to update by its `_id` which guarantees this will only match a single doc.

Comment: Actually, doesn't it look for a teacher with `_id` inside the `Teacher` collection? I have the same teacher doc stored in an array inside another collection.

Comment: Yes, `Teacher.update` will only update docs in that model's collection.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I need `multi`... strangely, locally this update is working, but not on my server. That's why I'm asking here if there's something wrong with my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64904/discussion-between-johnnyhk-and-c-porto).